# Morphological comparison of adjectives ending in "-ic"

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

[Page 267 of *Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AvmzBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA267&ots=gKt0QYooyf&dq=%22-est%20forms%20except%20in%20special%20circumstances%22&hl=es&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q=%22-est%20forms%20except%20in%20special%20circumstances%22&f=false) reads

> Adjectives ending in -**ic** (comic, rustic, etc.), -**ive** (active,
> restive, etc.), and -**ous** (famous, odious, virtuous, etc.) do not have
> -*er* and *-est* forms *except in special circumstances*.

What special circumstances is the author referring to?

Secondly, what would such forms be for *comic*? *comic**k**er/est*?

Comment: In a dictinoary search, I found ... *nativest*  *positivest* *curiousest* *jealousest*

Comment: Because those adjectives already have suffixes (*-ive, -ic, -ous*) and two suffixes (second in this case being *-er/est*) don't attach to a single word in English?

Comment: I don't know what circumstances are referred to by the author, although I suspect he's talking about words that have those ‘endings’ (not ‘suffixes’). And yes, the comparative and superlative of *comic* would be *comi**ck**er* and *comi**ck**est* respectively.

Comment: 'Chicer' and 'chicest' are attested. 'Comic' tends not to grade, @Decapitated. 'A more comical sketch is hard to imagine' uses the expected adjective here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had to deconstruct those comparatives to figure out what the hell the root was...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 1)  **exceptions to ‘<c> followed by <e, i, y> is pronounced /s/’:** 
 (with /k/) arced, arcing, Celt, Celtic (but the Glasgow football team
is /ˈseltɪk/), chicer, chicest, sceptic (in British spelling) and words  
beginning encephal- /eŋkefəl-/ (also 
/ensefəl-/).  https://books.openedition.org/obp/2191?lang=es

Comment: On Sunday I was a picnicker; It was the *picnickest.

Comment: Any adjective with a 1-syllable ending is not monosyllabic, and none of these endings finish with a vowel, so morphological comparison doesn't happen with them. Therefore there are no rules to follow, which means strike off in your own direction and see if anybody follows you.

Comment: “Except in special circumstances” is one of the ways to indicate that there are exceptions to a statement or “rule,” each of which may have its own explanation.

Comment: What's wrong with *more comic* and *most comic* for your comparative and superlative?

Answer (score 1):

One example of the special case would **curiouser**, an *er* form of the adjective **curious**. It is a special case of neologism derived from a work of literature, in this case, *Alice in Wonderland*.

Comment: I don't think any of these others caught on though: *T was brillig, and the slithy toves Did gyre and gimble in the wabe...* (Also, say *curiousest* three times quickly.)

Comment: _The comparative and superlative forms curiouser and curiousest are regarded as informal or nonstandard_ https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curious#Usage_notes